# Getting distinct rows from Realm table in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm

I am using **Realm** database for iOS application where i have a use case in which i want to filter result set by distinct values for a particular field. This field is not a primary key of the realm table.

I was not able to construct query for that.

Sample query :

```
RLMResults *allFiles = [FileRLMObject objectsInRealm:realmObject where:@"colA == %@", @"test1"];
```

**FileRLMObject** is a subclass of **RLMObject**  from **realm library**

here table contains one column with name **colB**. While getting allFiles results, i want to get rows which are having distinct **colB** values.

Any suggestions how i can achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realm doesn't support distinct queries yet. You can subscribe [issue #1103](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1103)  to track progress on that.

As a workaround, you could query for all values for `colB` first and then select objects for each value of it, as seen below:

```
 NSArray *values = [FileRLMObject.allObjects valueForKey:"type"];
 NSSet *distinctValues = [NSSet setWithArray:values];
 NSMutableArray *allFiles = [NSMutableArray new];
 for (NSString *colB in distinctValues) {
      // This takes the firstObject.
      // You might want to modify the sort order to make sure
      // you get a certain object in case that there may exist 
      // multiple objects per distinct value.
      FileRLMObject *object = [FileRLMObject objectsWhere:@"colB == ?", colB].firstObject;
      [allFiles appendObject:object];
 }
```

Comment: It looks like getting all the data and looking for distinct elements.... isn't it possible to filter without iterating over all rows?

Comment: Not at the moment. We're currently working on that, but I can't give an ETA yet.